# Render card based on pet type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, jsx

I'm trying to render a card when it's a cat with a purple background and a card with a background blue when it's a dog based on type. the card is designed to be unique to each animal.

[dog card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z84Hn.png)
[cat card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0KXr.png)

**json file**

```
"animals": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "Cat",
      
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "Dog",
      
    }
  ]
```

**AnimalAdopt.tsx**

```
const AnimalAdopt = ({ animals }) => {

return (
    <Card className="list-group">
        {animals.map((animals) => (
            <DogCard>

                <HeaderContainer>
                    <HeaderCard>
                        <Image>
                            <img src={animals.photo} width='120px' height='120px' alt='Picture of a cute dog' />
                        </Image>
                
                        <Name>{animals.name}</Name>
                       
                    </HeaderCard>
                </HeaderContainer>
```

**App.tsx**

```
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/pets';
function App() {


  const [animals, setanimals] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((result) => {
      setanimals(result.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (

    <div>
      < Header />
      {animals ? <AnimalAdopt animals={animals} /> : < Loading />}
    </div>


  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `animals.map((animal) => { const Card = animal.type === "Cat" ? CatCard : DogCard; return <Card>...</Card>; });`

Answer (score -1):

```
    "animals": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "type": "Cat",
    "color":"xyz color code"
          
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "type": "Dog",
    "color":"xyz color code"
          
        }
      ]

AnimalAdopt.tsx

const AnimalAdopt = ({ animals }) => {

return (
    <Card className="list-group">
        {animals.map((animal) => (
            <DogCard style={{backgroundColor:`${animal.color}`}}>

                <HeaderContainer>
                    <HeaderCard>
                        <Image>
                            <img src={animal.photo} width='120px' height='120px' alt='Picture of a cute dog' />
                        </Image>
                
                        <Name>{animal.name}</Name>
                       
                    </HeaderCard>
                </HeaderContainer>
```

Answer (score -1):

"animals": [
{
"id": 1,
"type": "Cat",
"color":"xyz color code"

```
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "Dog",
"color":"xyz color code"
      
    }
  ]
```

AnimalAdopt.tsx

const AnimalAdopt = ({ animals }) => {

return (

{animals.map((animal) => (
<DogCard style={{backgroundColor:`${animal.color}`}}>

```
            <HeaderContainer>
                <HeaderCard>
                    <Image>
                        <img src={animal.photo} width='120px' height='120px' alt='Picture of a cute dog' />
                    </Image>
            
                    <Name>{animal.name}</Name>
                   
                </HeaderCard>
            </HeaderContainer>
```

or you can use simple way like that

"animals": [
{
"id": 1,
"type": "Cat",

```
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "type": "Dog",
  
}
```

]
AnimalAdopt.tsx

const AnimalAdopt = ({ animals }) => {

return (

{animals.map((animals) => (
<DogCard  style={{backgroundColor:`#${Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}`}}>

```
            <HeaderContainer>
                <HeaderCard>
                    <Image>
                        <img src={animals.photo} width='120px' height='120px' alt='Picture of a cute dog' />
                    </Image>
            
                    <Name>{animals.name}</Name>
                   
                </HeaderCard>
            </HeaderContainer>
```